# Order documents by multiple geolocations

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to `ElasticSearch` and I try to create an index for companies that come with multiple branches in the city.

Each of the branches, it has its own geolocation point.

My companies document looks like this:

```
{
    "company_name": "Company X",
    "branch": [
        {
            "address": {
                // ... other fields
                "location": "0.0000,1.1111"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The index have the following mapping:

```
{
  "companies": {
    "mappings": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "ids": {
            "match": "id",
            "match_mapping_type": "long",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "long"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "company_locations": {
            "match": "location",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "geo_point"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "branch": {
          "properties": {
            "address": {
              "properties": {
                // ...
                "location": {
                  "type": "geo_point"
                },
                // ...
              }
            },
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, in the ElasticSearch I've indexed the following documents:

```
{
    "company_name": "Company #1",
    "branch": [
        {
            "address": {
                "location": "39.615,19.8948"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and

```
{
    "company_name": "Company #2",
    "branch": [
        {
            "address": {
                "location": "39.586,19.9028"
            }
        },
        {
            "address": {
                "location": "39.612,19.9134"
            }
        },
        {
            "address": {
                "location": "39.607,19.8946"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now what is my problem. If I try to run the following search query, unfortunately the company displayed first is the `Company #2` although the geodistance query has the location data of the `Company #1`:

```
GET companies/_search
{
  
  "fields": [
    "company_name", 
    "branch.address.location"
  ],
  "_source": false,
  "sort": [
    {
      "_geo_distance": {
        "branch.address.location": {
          "lon": 39.615,
          "lat": 19.8948
        },
        "order": "asc",
        "unit": "km"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to sort the search results using this method?

Please keep in mind that if for example search with a geolocation that is more close to some geolocations of the "Comapny #2", in this case I need the `Company #2` to be first.

Finally, if the setup I have isn't correct for what I require, if there's any other way to achieve that same result with different document structure, please let me know. I am still in the beginning of the project, and It's simple to adapt to what is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html) says "Geopoint expressed as a string with the format: "lat,lon"."
Your location is "location": "39.615,19.8948", maybe the query must be below:

```
 "branch.address.location": {
     "lat": 39.615,
     "lon": 19.8948
  }
```

My Tests:

```
PUT idx_test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "branch": {
        "properties": {
          "address": {
            "properties": {
              "location": {
                "type": "geo_point"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST idx_test/_doc/1
{
  "company_name": "Company #1",
  "branch": [
    {
      "address": {
        "location": "39.615,19.8948"
      }
    }
    ]
}

POST idx_test/_doc/2
{
    "company_name": "Company #2",
    "branch": [
        {
            "address": {
                "location": "39.586,19.9028"
            }
        },
        {
            "address": {
                "location": "39.612,19.9134"
            }
        },
        {
            "address": {
                "location": "39.607,19.8946"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Search by location "39.607,19.8946" company #2

```
GET idx_test/_search?
{
  "fields": [
    "company_name",
    "branch.address.location"
  ],
  "_source": false,
  "sort": [
    {
      "_geo_distance": {
        "branch.address.location": {
          "lat": 39.607,
          "lon": 19.8946
        },
        "order": "asc", 
        "unit": "km"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Response:

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "idx_test",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": null,
    "fields": {
      "branch.address.location": [
        {
          "coordinates": [
            19.9028,
            39.586
          ],
          "type": "Point"
        },
        {
          "coordinates": [
            19.9134,
            39.612
          ],
          "type": "Point"
        },
        {
          "coordinates": [
            19.8946,
            39.607
          ],
          "type": "Point"
        }
      ],
      "company_name": [
        "Company #2"
      ]
    },
    "sort": [
      0
    ]
  },
  {
    "_index": "idx_test",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": null,
    "fields": {
      "branch.address.location": [
        {
          "coordinates": [
            19.8948,
            39.615
          ],
          "type": "Point"
        }
      ],
      "company_name": [
        "Company #1"
      ]
    },
    "sort": [
      0.8897252783915647
    ]
  }
]
```

Search by location "39.615,19.8948" company #1

```
GET idx_test/_search?
{
  "fields": [
    "company_name",
    "branch.address.location"
  ],
  "_source": false,
  "sort": [
    {
      "_geo_distance": {
        "branch.address.location": {
          "lat": 39.615,
          "lon": 19.8948
        },
        "order": "asc", 
        "unit": "km"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Response

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "idx_test",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": null,
    "fields": {
      "branch.address.location": [
        {
          "coordinates": [
            19.8948,
            39.615
          ],
          "type": "Point"
        }
      ],
      "company_name": [
        "Company #1"
      ]
    },
    "sort": [
      0
    ]
  },
  {
    "_index": "idx_test",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": null,
    "fields": {
      "branch.address.location": [
        {
          "coordinates": [
            19.9028,
            39.586
          ],
          "type": "Point"
        },
        {
          "coordinates": [
            19.9134,
            39.612
          ],
          "type": "Point"
        },
        {
          "coordinates": [
            19.8946,
            39.607
          ],
          "type": "Point"
        }
      ],
      "company_name": [
        "Company #2"
      ]
    },
    "sort": [
      0.8897285575578558
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: First I'd like to thank you for your answer. Then, I'd like to mention that in the documentation it seems like both geolocation data expressions are equivalent. In addition, from what I can recall from my memory, I've tested the geo point expression you mentioned in your answer and still didn't worked :(.

Comment: I ran an example with your samples and it returned Company #1 in the top position. What I did is correct the lat, lon as they are reversed.

Comment: that was the behaviour I had on my local dev env too. But when I used a `lat` and `lot` that was closer to one of the `Company #2` locations data, the sort was again with the `Company #1` first and the `Company #2` second while the requirement is to have first the `Company #2` and first the `Company #1`.

Comment: I put my tests in answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. You are right, it was my fault. I appreciate your time and your efforts to help me. Have a great day ! :)